# Why does my implementation of strlcat gives a segmentation fault when the original does not?

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault

I am writing a re-implementation of strlcat as an exercise. I have perform several tests and they produce similar result. However on one particular case, my function gives an segmentation fault error while the original does not, could you explain to me why? I am not allowed to use any of the standard library function, that is why I have re-implemented strlen().

Here is the code I have written :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int ft_strlen(char *s)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return (i);
}

unsigned int    ft_strlcat(char *dest, char *src, unsigned int size)
{
    size_t  i;
    int     d_len;
    int     s_len;

    i = 0;
    d_len = ft_strlen(dest);
    s_len = ft_strlen(src);
    if (!src || !*src)
        return (d_len);
    while ((src[i] && (i < (size - d_len - 1))))
    {
        dest[i + d_len] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i + d_len] = '\0';
    return (d_len + s_len);
}

int main(void)
{
    char s1[5] = "Hello";
    char s2[] = " World!";

printf("ft_strcat :: %s :: %u :: sizeof %lu\n", s1, ft_strlcat(s1, s2, sizeof(s1)), sizeof(s1));
    // printf("strlcat :: %s :: %lu :: sizeof %lu\n", s1, strlcat(s1, s2, sizeof(s1)), sizeof(s1));
}
```

The output using strlcat is : `strlcat :: Hello World! :: 12 :: sizeof 5`. I am on macOS and I am using clang to compile if that can be of some help.

Comment: may have something to do with `sizeof` a string buffer is always 1 more than the length return from `strlen()` of a string buffer.  Double check value of `i` in `dest[i + d_len] = src[i];` and `while ((src[i] && (i < (size - d_len - 1))))` while stepping through code in a debugger .

Comment: Use `size_t` not `int` or `unsigned int`.

Comment: The `s1[5]` array isn't big enough to hold `"Hello"` - that needs 6 characters (one for the null terminator).

Comment: What makes you think `strlcat` isn't invoking *undefined behavior*? Turn on address sanitizer (add `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` to your compile-time arguments) and you'll see it clearly is.

Comment: The declaration, `char s1[5] = "Hello";` is *valid* (in C) but it will not include the nul terminator in the array. That is **required** for almost all C functions that uses strings.

Comment: In particular, it's required for `strlcat()`, since `strlen(dest)` looks for it.

Comment: `s1` needs enough space to contain the _concatenated_ result. So, how about: `char s1[100] = "Hello";` With the given data [lengths], you could use at a minimum a length of 13, but why be stingy?

Comment: Emperor_Udan, where is the detailed  definition of what `strlcat()` is to do? Like [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlcat)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ft_strlcat()` is not so bad, but it expects pointers to *strings*.  `main()` is troublesome: `s1` lacks a *null character*: so `s1` is not a *string*.

```
//char s1[5] = "Hello";
char s1[] = "Hello"; // Use a string
```

`s1[]` too small for the concatenated string `"HelloWorld"`

```
char s1[11 /* or more */] = "Hello"; // Use a string
```

`"%lu"` matches `unsigned long`.  `size_t` from `sizeof` matches `"%zu"`.

---

Some `ft_strlcat()` issues:

**`unsigned, int` vs. `size_t`**

`unsigned, int` too narrow for *long* strings.  Use `size_t`  to handle all *strings*.

**Test too late**

`if (!src || ...)` is too late as prior `ft_strlen(src);` invokes UB when `src == NULL`.

**`const`**

`ft_strlcat()` should use a pointer to `const` to allow usage with `const` strings with `src`.

**Advanced: `restrict`**

Use `restrict` so the compiler can assume `dest, src` do not overlap and emit more efficient code - assuming they should not overlap.

**Corner cases**

It does not handle some pesky corner cases like when `d_len >= size`, but I will leave that detailed analysis for later.

---

**Suggested signature**

```
// unsigned int    ft_strlcat(char *dest, char *src, unsigned int size)
size_t ft_strlcat(char * restrict dest, const char * restrict src, size_t size)
```

---

Some **untested** code for your consideration:

- Tries to mimic [`strlcat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlcat).
- Returns sum of string lengths, but not more that `size`.
- Does not examine more than `size` characters to prevent reading out of bounds.
- Does not append a *null character* when not enough room.
- Does not check for `dst, src` as `NULL`.  Add if you like.
- Does not handle overlapping `dest`, `src`.  To do so is tricky unless library routines available.
- Use `unsigned char *` pointer to properly handle rare signed non-2's complement `char`.

```
size_t my_strlcat(char * restrict dst, const char * restrict src, size_t size) {
  const size_t size_org = size;

  // Walk dst
  unsigned char *d = (unsigned char*) dst;
  while (size > 0 && *d) {
    d++;
    size--;
  }
  if (size == 0) {
    return size_org;
  }

  // Copy src to dst
  const unsigned char *s = (const unsigned char*) src;
  while (size > 0 && *s) {
    *d++ = *s++;
    size--;
  }
  if (size == 0) {
    return size_org;
  }

  *d = '\0';
  return (size_t) (d - (unsigned char*) dst);
}
```

If the return value is less than `size`, success!

Answer (score 1):

1. `s1` is not even long enough to accommodate the "Hello"
2. Use the correct type for sizes.

```
size_t ft_strlcat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t len)
{
    char *savedDest = dest;
    if(dest && src && len)
    {
        while(*dest && len)
        {
            len--;
            dest++;
        }
        if(len)
        {
            while((*dest = *src) && len)
            {
                len--;
                dest++;
                *src++;
            }
        }
        if(!len) dest[-1] = 0;
    }
    return dest ? dest - savedDest : 0;
}
```

3. Also your `printf` invokes undefined behaviour as order of function parameters evaluation is not determined. It should be:

```
int main(void)
{
    char s1[5] = "Hello";     //will only work for len <= sizeof(s1) as s1 is not null character terminated
    char s2[] = " World!";

    size_t result = ft_strlcat(s1, s2, sizeof(s1));
    printf("ft_strcat :: %s ::  %zu :: sizeof %zu\n", s1, result, sizeof(s1));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8hhbKjsbx

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica asked another one about `(uintptr_t)NULL  - (uintptr_t)NULL`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the problem is "likely"